# Printing strings that have chars separated by " + " and strings themselves separated by " , "

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some variables:

```
A1 = 'abc'
B1 = 'def'
C1 = 'ghi'
```

I want to write code that prints A1, B1, C1 in the following format:

`a+b+c, d+e+f, g+h+i`

so in every string value the chars get separated by a `+` and the strings themselves are separated by a `,`.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: umm no, i am not enrolled in any programming classes, i have a personal project i am working on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [11]: str.join?
Namespace:  Python builtin
Docstring:
S.join(iterable) -> string

Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the
iterable.  The separator between elements is S.
```

```
In [12]: ", ".join("+".join(chars) for chars in [A1, B1, C1])
Out[12]: 'a+b+c, d+e+f, g+h+i'
```